# Update attributedText on a dequeued cell UITextView make the app freeze

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, nstextattachment, nstextcontainer

I'm currently stuck down a big wall...

I'm using custom `UITableViewCell` containing `UITextView` containing custom `NSTextAttachment` images.

Each `NSTextAttachment` overrides the

```
 - (CGRect)attachmentBoundsForTextContainer:(NSTextContainer *)textContainer proposedLineFragment:(CGRect)lineFrag glyphPosition:(CGPoint)position characterIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex;
```

and

```
- (UIImage *)imageForBounds:(CGRect)imageBounds
              textContainer:(NSTextContainer *)textContainer
             characterIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex;
```

from the `NSTextAttachmentContainer` protocol.

The goal here is to display images with different sizes and adapt the bounds to the available space.

I also need to compute the cell height using the `sizeThatFits` statement on a dedicated cell before caching it.

Everything just worked fine until today when I tried to list a particular series of contents.

When dequeuing an old cell to display a brand new, my app just freeze in the `[_textView setAttributedString:myAttributedText];` statement (`[NSATSTypesetter beginLineWithGlyphAtIndex:]` in the stack).

I just tried everything to avoid recreating cells every times (which actually works) in vain.

Here's what I found:

- The issue remains even if I "hard code" return the cell height values.
- Changing `NSTextAttachment` bounds (and keeping the cells height) seems to make the bug disappear without any logic...
- It's clearly a devil combination of content, because if I change the cell heights to make the dequeue occurs later, everything works fine. Actually the two cells involved both contains a text including just one image.
- I looked at the `- (void)prepareForReuse` method and tried to reset the `UITextView` state, also in vain.
- Re-creating a brand new `UITextView` each time the cell is dequeued seems to solve the problem.

Any idea? Do I need to know something essential about the dequeuing system or the `NSTextAttachmentContainer` protocol?

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
The only thing I found to resolve this issue is to do that:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    // Reset text
    _contentTextView.attributedText = nil;
    [_contentTextView sizeToFit];
}
```

The `sizeToFit` statement is here really important!

Comment: Have you ever found the cause and a solution to this? Just got into a very similar issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no...